# How to change text inside a label tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I change text `Add Your Image` to `Change Your Image`.

```
<label class="control-label col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 btn green feedbackImg" style="text-align:center;">
    Add Your Image
    <input type="file" name="data[Feedback][img]" class="form-control hide single_img_btn" id="1" style="display: none;">  
</label>
```

```js
$('.feedbackImg').text('Change Your Image');
```

But it changed the `label` as follows :

```
<label class="control-label col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 btn green feedbackImg" style="text-align:center;">
    Add Your Image
</label>
```

That means it remove input tag also. How can I keep all same except the text only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can change your HTML then simply wrap the text you want to change in a `span` to make it easier to select:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 btn green feedbackImg" style="text-align:center;">
    <span>Add Your Image</span>
    <input type="file" name="data[Feedback][img]" class="form-control hide single_img_btn" id="1" style="display: none;">  
</label>
```

```js
$('.feedbackImg span').text('Change Your Image');
```

If you can't change the HTML, then you would need to amend your JS code to retreive and amend the textNode itself:

```
$('.feedbackImg').contents().first()[0].textContent = 'Change Your Image';
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the `textNode`

1. **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** - for getting all nodes including text and comments
2. **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** - get first element , which is textNode(label)
3. **[`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)** - update the text content with new text

**CODE:**

```js
$('.feedbackImg').contents().eq(0).replaceWith('Change Your Image');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 btn green feedbackImg" style="text-align:center;">
  Add Your Image
  <input type="file" name="data[Feedback][img]" class="form-control hide single_img_btn" id="1" style="display: none;">
</label>
```

OR

```js
$('.feedbackImg').contents()[0].nodeValue = 'Change Your Image';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 btn green feedbackImg" style="text-align:center;">
  Add Your Image
  <input type="file" name="data[Feedback][img]" class="form-control hide single_img_btn" id="1" style="display: none;">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the html to this

```
<label class="control-label col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 btn green feedbackImg" style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="image_label">Add Your Image</span>
    <input type="file" name="data[Feedback][img]" class="form-control hide single_img_btn" id="1" style="display: none;">  
</label>
```

And then in jquery

```
$('.image_label').text('Change Your Image');
```